# How to pronounce Ksana?

Tags: learning

It's [刹那](http://www.hsk.academy/en/words/%E5%88%B9%E9%82%A3) in Chinese, is the smallest unit of time, from Sanskrit.

My question: How to pronounce Ksana in Sanskrit ?

Please leave phonetic symbol or click [here](http://forvo.com/search/Ksana/).

Answer (score 1):

[www.spokensanskrit.de](http://www.spokensanskrit.de/index.php?script=DI&beginning=0+&tinput=moment+&trans=Translate&direction=ES) says,

```
क्षण    kṣaṇa   m. n.   moment
```

Comment: I am asking how to speak Ksana, or what it is sounds like ?

Answer (score 1):

In Hindi, it's क्षण which you pronounce like the English word **Shun**.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for a sound ...saaa...shaa sana ksana k is like shhh..

Comment: I still do not understand :(

Comment: Ok the word ksana ( minute , moment ) is pronounced as a shhh sound it's tricky some letters in Sanskrit ( mother of all languages )are pronounced different much like in English where a J ...could be a Y sound or sometimes there are silent letter like H in the word honours ...there's a English to Sanskrit tattoe site on Google but sure of Chinese to Sanskrit //hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**刹那** *chànà* **क्षण** **kṣaṇa**.
An indefinite space of time, a moment, an instant; the shortest measure of time, as kalpa is the longest; it is defined as **一念** a thought; but according to another definition **60 kṣaṇa** equal one finger-snap, **90** a **thought 念**, **4,500 a minute**; there are other definitions. In each **kṣaṇa** 900 persons are born and die.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a pronunciation example of "*kṣa*" in [*kṣaṇa* (क्षण)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/kshana#sanskrit), in [this video](https://youtu.be/p4fQIa2q2kQ?t=950) at the timestamp already part of the URL, which is 15:50.

In that example, he speaks [*kṣaya* (क्षय)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/kshaya#sanskrit).